# Multiple disk controller cards and RAID1

Tags: hard-drive, raid-1

I'm creating a btrfs RAID1 array, and I have two SATA3 controllers - one on the motherboard and another in a PCIe slot.  For simplicty's sake, let's say I only have two drivers, sda and sdb.  Would I be better off hooking them both to the same controller or should one be on the MB controller and the other on the CARD controller.  Splitting them across controllers seems like a good idea since if one entire controller died you would still have a working drive.  But would I be sacrificing anything (I/O speed? CPU load? An OCD feeling of symmetry/balance?  Something I haven't considered?) by not connecting both drives to the same controller?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using only the PCI-E slot as the hardware/firmware on them tends to be better than the on-board controllers.

Many on-board controllers tend to do what's known as "fake-RAID" - working like a hardware RAID, but actually only doing a software RAID so you don't get the performance of a true hardware RAID.

As an extra to your question, you can't achieve RAID using the on-board and the PCE-E card if one drive is attached to each.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but this is a btrfs RAID array - so it's 100% software-based.  That means you *can* achieve RAID with one drive attached to each controller, and the RAID options of the controllers don't matter, since the controllers are functioning as single-device controllers, not RAID controllers.

Comment: Whoops! Sorry! OK, then I think you'll be safe and, in theory (I don't know about this but logic is sending me down the route), if any one controller went down you could connect the new drive to any free port (regardless of card) and add it to the array (because it's software). I wonder, however, by spanning the array over controllers (talking about performance) that you may actually see a small drop because you've added extra data buses into the equation, rather than all the data being kept on a single piece of hardware specifically designed to deal with RAID data?

Answer (score 0):

The biggest performance hit would be from the difference in speed of your controllers.  If your onboard controller benchmarked 50% faster speed than a card, then you would a see a 50% performance hit when data is accessed on the slower controller.  But if your controller benchmarked at the exact same speed, I bet you would not see any real performance hit over the drives being on the same controller.

The best thing you might do is benchmark your controllers first separately using the same drive to get a feel for what the performance of your controllers is.  Then setup some arrays on the controllers using different combos then test and measure the performance of the arrays and compare to the benchamarks of your controllers independently.  Then, make sense of the data and choose you're best configuration.

There are so many variables between drive difference, controller differences, MB chipsets handling the data in varying ways, and even how the software handles things that what performance you really see will be heavily dependent on the variables and parameters of your setup.

So in short, you shouldn't see any performance hit due to splitting controllers, but the best performance can not be figured until you setup varying configurations, benchmark them, and compare them.

Can you run a 2 drive RAID 10 using btrfs like Linux MD Raid?

Comment: This might be a bad assumption, but I'm assuming that for SATA2 interfaces and above and for rotating media (not SSDs), the I/O speed is largely limited by the drive speed - 3Gb/s = 300MB/s = more than twice as much as I've ever seen a HDD sustain.  And small data bursts are severely limited by seek time.  So HDD matching would be more important than controller matching.  But you're right that experimenting is likely the only way to know for sure for a given configuration.

Comment: And yes, btrfs has a RAID10 mode that you could make with 2 drives (you could even make it with 1 drive and 4 partitions), but with only 2 drives I'm not sure you could see a speed benefit and a redundancy benefit simultaneously.  Seems like RAID1 with 2 drives would give you the same performance and redundancy as RAID10 with two drives...

Comment: Linux MD RAID10 on two drives was twice as fast as MD RAID1 on our server; seems ridiculous to me, but that was what our benchmarks showed using a HDD tach.